How do I view the PARTITION BY values on an Iceberg table?
I have Iceberg tables that were created with PARTITONED BY clauses like shown here:
CREATE TABLE prod.db.sample (
    id bigint,
    data string,
    category string,
    ts timestamp)
USING iceberg
PARTITIONED BY (bucket(16, id), days(ts), category);

How do I view what the current PARTITIONED BY settings are on a table?
Is there a query or SHOW or DESCRIBE statement that will show the settings?
I'm attempting to programmatically manage the PARTIONION BY settings.
I can use the ALTER TABLE ADD/DROP/REPLACE PARTITION FIELD commands, but I need to be able to view what the current settings are.
I know the information is in the Metadata JSON file, but I'm hoping I don't have to read and parse it.
I also saw there is a SHOW CREATE TABLE {table} command but this would be even harder to parse.
I'm using PySpark, Spark 3.5, Iceberg 1.4.3, AWS EMR 7.1

i haven't used apache-iceberg, but maybe DESCRIBE EXTENDED table_name ?

did you try "desc formatted table_name"? This shows the partition details, at least in Hive. Also, please specify what settings you want to see? You just want to see the partition details or anything else. Thanks!

Thank for the help.
Both DESCRIBE EXTENDED {table} and DESCRIBE FORMATTED {table} will show the PARTITIONED BY settings.
df = spark.sql("DESCRIBE EXTENDED gdc.greg_test2.sample")
df.show(100, truncate=False)

+----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|col_name                    |data_type                                                                                              |comment|
+----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+
|id                          |bigint                                                                                                 |NULL   |
|data                        |string                                                                                                 |NULL   |
|category                    |string                                                                                                 |NULL   |
|ts                          |timestamp                                                                                              |NULL   |
|                            |                                                                                                       |       |
|# Partitioning              |                                                                                                       |       |
|Part 0                      |bucket(16, id)                                                                                         |       |
|Part 1                      |days(ts)                                                                                               |       |
|Part 2                      |category                                                                                               |       |
|                            |                                                                                                       |       |
|# Metadata Columns          |                                                                                                       |       |
|_spec_id                    |int                                                                                                    |       |
|_partition                  |struct<id_bucket:int,ts_day:date,category:string>                                                      |       |
|_file                       |string                                                                                                 |       |
|_pos                        |bigint                                                                                                 |       |
|_deleted                    |boolean                                                                                                |       |
|                            |                                                                                                       |       |
|# Detailed Table Information|                                                                                                       |       |
|Name                        |gdc.greg_test2.sample                                                                                  |       |
|Type                        |MANAGED                                                                                                |       |
|Location                    |s3://BUCKET/gdc/databases/greg_test2/sample                                                            |       |
|Provider                    |iceberg                                                                                                |       |
|Owner                       |hadoop                                                                                                 |       |
|Table Properties            |[current-snapshot-id=none,format=iceberg/parquet,format-version=2,write.parquet.compression-codec=zstd]|       |
+----------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------+

